# Timer is undefined

Tags: java, timer, undefined

I'm trying to make a timer that will make my ball move. The drawing part is no problem, but the timer keeps saying it's undefined even though I did exactly the same in my previous projects.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SpaceInvaders extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel bg;
private JButton start, reset;
private int xcora = 255, xcorb = 290, gestart = 0;
private Timer shoot;

public SpaceInvaders(){
    //MAKING FRAME
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(600,700);
    setFocusable(true);
    setResizable(false);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //BUTTONS AND SHIT
    bg = new JPanel(); add(bg); bg.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580,600)); bg.setBackground(Color.BLACK); bg.setFocusable(true); 
    start = new JButton("Start"); add(start); start.addActionListener(this);
    reset = new JButton("Reset"); add(reset); reset.addActionListener(this);

    //TIMERS
    shoot = new Timer(100, this); //This isn't working somehow

    setVisible(true);
   }
```

I let out the actionPerformed part, because it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `import java.util.Timer;`. It should be `javax.swing.Timer`

Answer (score 1):

In JDK, `Timer` class is present in 2 packages

```
javax.swing
java.util
```

and your code has imported both of them

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```

importing a specific Timer (whichever you want) should solve the issue

do either `import java.util.Timer` or `javax.swing.Timer`. Don't forget to remove

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```